# How to prevent datatable from updating column header text

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have complex header for data table and I attach header rows before table initialization.

However when data is received from server it updated the header I don't want to be updated.

```
<tr role="row" class="header-row first-row-table-header">
    <th colspan="6"></th>
    <th class="dt-center" colspan="1">2015</th>
    <th class="dt-center" colspan="1">2016</th>
    <th colspan="2"></th>
</tr>
<tr role="row" class="header-row second-row-table-header">
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Make</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Badge /Series</th>
    <th>Series</th>
    <th>Trans.</th>
    <th>Dec</th>
    <th>Jan</th>
    <th>Age. per Period</th>
    <th>Total</th></tr>
<tr role="row" class="header-row third-row-table-header summary-header">
    <th class="dt-right" colspan="6">Total Per Month</th>
    <th column-data="Dec 2015"></th>
    <th column-data="Jan 2016"></th>
    <th column-data="Average"></th>
    <th column-data="Total"></th>
</tr>
```

My column Definition for 
When data arrived the header on first row expected to show Columns with 2015 and 2016 title. However it shows 'Dec' and 'Jan'. 
Column Definition for those 2 columns are

```
{
    data: "Dec 2015"
    headerGroup: "Dec 2015"
    orderable: false
    targets: 6
    title: "Dec"
}
```

and

```
 {
      data: "Jan 2016"
      headerGroup: "Jan 2016"
      orderable: false
      targets: 7
      title: "Jan"
 }
```

Data from server is as below:

```
  {
      Average: "1"
      Badge: ""
      Dec 2015: "1"
      Jan 2016: "1"
      Make: "BMW"
      Model: "M135i"
      Series: "F20"
      Total: "2"
      Transmission: "Auto"
      Year: "2012"
  }
```

How can I prevent changing the header column text for the first row after data update?

PS: Here is showing the problem. You might need to wait for a while as server is slow.

http://live.datatables.net/habokasi/4/edit

Comment: where is the javascript code?

Comment: Nothing fancy. Datatable with ajax call.

Comment: you cant tag a question with a javascript tag, ask for a fix in javascript while insist not to attach even a single line of code...

Comment: no worries. I ll add javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the header row with `<thead>` otherwise JQuery datatable will use the "title" specified in the columnDef. https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table for more info about html table structure.

Or you can set the correct Header title in your columnDef:

```
{
data: "Dec 2015"
headerGroup: "Dec 2015"
orderable: false
targets: 6
title: "2015"
```

}

Comment: I already have the thead in my html. That's why I append it to $('thead'). Also there is no data associated with first header row and it only for readability of the table.

Comment: sry looking at the code again looks like you are appending the header rows to the '<thead>' tag. the snippet didn't show that...

Comment: Doesn't work. The first header should read '2015', '2016' and the column below it should read 'Dec',  'Jan'. In your exit both changed to 2015 and 2016